# iPhone not receiving push notifications - Appcelerator/Xtify

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, xtify

I am currently working on a mobile project using Appcelerator and Xtify to handle push notifications.

My iPhone token has been archived and registered to Xtify successfully(it is listed on Xtify portal), but when I tried to send push notification from Xtify test page, my iPhone didn't get any message

Anything else I need to do with Xtify to get push message?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your push certificate. Did you upload the correct development push certificate to Xtify with the correct password?